# Matlab code for wigner ville distribution

Tags: frequency-spectrum, real-time

I wanna to have a wigner ville distribution spec.and need code in matlab

Comment: My understanding is that asking for code is off topic here. You could put forth your own effort and many people would help you refine it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find several flavors of the Wigner-Ville diistributions in the [Time-Frequency Toolbox](http://tftb.nongnu.org/)

From the [Contents.m](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/tftb/tftb/mfiles/Contents.m?content-type=text%2Fplain&revision=HEAD) file

```
%   tfrspwv  - Smoothed Pseudo Wigner-Ville distribution.   
%   tfrwv    - Wigner-Ville distribution.
%   tfrpwv   - Pseudo Wigner-Ville distribution.            
%   tfrspaw  - Smoothed Pseudo Affine Wigner distributions.
%   tfrrpwv  - Reassigned Pseudo Wigner-Ville distribution.
```

Now, based on your comments, `wigner1.m` `find_chirplets.m` can be found in another toolbox, namely [DiscreteTFDs: Time-Frequency Analysis Software](http://tfd.sourceforge.net/), where you can find the following functions (see [Contents.m](http://tfd.sourceforge.net/Contents.m)):

```
%   demo_wigner4   - demo of the type IV Wigner distribution
%   wigner1
%   qwigner2
%   qwigner4 (even length signals only)
%   wigner4 (odd length signals only)
%   lwigner   - L-Wigner distributions
```

Comment: I can not use these codes in matlab.when i search in help of matlab there is nothing to show.version is 2015b.if i take a mistake please guid me with a sample.

Comment: Can i have your e-mail?

Comment: For what? Installation procedures are describe at the beginning of http://tftb.nongnu.org/tutorial.pdf

Comment: I did not recieved exe files to install.only have m-file such as demo-cohen and stft.m ...... . please send me your email to guide me.thanks

Comment: Hello.l want these m.files : wigner1.m and find_chirplets.m.thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. You might be talking about another toolbox

Comment: I have a displacment signal and want to process on it.i tried to do but could not . can you help me? How can l send you the signal?

Comment: I dont have m-files such as affine class distribution and cohen class dis. And reassigned billinear time-freq.

Comment: I believe the answer to your original question (codes for Wigner-Ville) was given (and could be accepted as such). If you have questions about the affine class, the Cohen class, or reassignment, they should be separated. Again, for the specific procesing of a signal, which is on topic, a specific question is advised